# This is a ll(1) of logic propositions?

Tags: propositional-calculus, formal-grammar, parsing

I have this is grammar :

```
F = F and F
F = F or F 
F = F => F
F = F <=> F
F = not F
F = (F)
D = a
```

but this grammar has a ambiguity , i'm Stripped a ambiguity like this :

```
F = F and A
F = A
A = F or B 
A = B
B = F => C
B = C
C = F <=> C
C=D
D = not F
D = (F)
D = a
```

its true or no ?

Answer (score 0):

No, your second grammar is still ambiguous - the production 'F = F and F' can derive 'F and F and F' two ways.

Comment: i added  :  F = F and A

Comment: and now ? ,,,??